# Errors with TIFF files

Tags: python, pygame, tiff

`TIFFReadDirectory: warning, Unknown field with tag 37724 (0x935c) encountered
 TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored`

I get this error when I run my program even though I don't use any TIFF files, and I don't know what that tag code means (I *have* googled it).

*I am not asking for someone to just "fix it," I want to know why it happens, and how to prevent it.*

This is my program, I think it is something involved in a module (possible pygame), because I have no TIFF files being loaded.

```
import random
import sys
import time
from pygame import *
import pygame
pygame.init()

 #------Easy-Change Variables
mouse_visibility = False
turtlespeed = 4

 #------Font
font = pygame.font.SysFont("C:/Python34/TurtleFont.ttf", 48)

 #------Theme Music & Sound Effects
pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/Python34/Jumpshot.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(1, 0.0)

chomp = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/Python34/chomp.wav")
 #------BG, Screen & Caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Turtle Trouble!')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 616))
bg_img = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/icebackground.png")
screen.blit(bg_img,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

 #------Image Preparation
turtle = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/turtle.png")
fish = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/fish.png")
endgame_turtle = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/endgame_turtle.png")

 #------Movement, Coords, Collisions & Fish
turtlepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(mouse_visibility)

turtle_rect = turtle.get_rect()
fish_rect = fish.get_rect()


points = 0
fish_pos_list = []

while pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[1] == False:
    time.wait(1)

while elapsed_time <= 45== True:
    elapsed_time = time.time() - game_time
    mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    text = font.render("Points: %s" % points, True, (0, 128, 0))
    screen.blit(text, (0, 0))

    new_fish = random.randint(0, 6)
    fish_x = random.randint(0, 943)
    fish_y = random.randint(0, 552)

    if mousepos[1] - turtlepos[1] < 0:
        turtlepos[1] -= turtlespeed
    else:
        turtlepos[1] += turtlespeed

    if mousepos[2] - turtlepos[2] < 0:
        turtlepos[2] -= turtlespeed
    else:
        turtlepos[2] += turtlespeed

    screen.blit(turtle_rect,(turtlepos[1],turtlepos[2]))
    pygame.display.flip()

    if new_fish == 0:
        screen.blit(fish_rect,(fish_x, fish_y))
        start_time = time.time()
        positions = {'x':fish_x, 'y':fish_y, 'fishtimer':start_time}
        fish_pos_list.append(positions)

    for position in fish_pos_list:
        if position['fishtimer'] >= 6:
            screen.blit(bg_img, (position['x'], position['y']), pygame.Rect(position['x'], position['y'], 81, 62))
            del fish_pos_list[0]
        else:
            break

    for position in fish_pos_list:
        if turtle_rect.colliderect(fish_rect):
            screen.blit(bg_img, (position['x'], position['y']), pygame.Rect(position['x'], position['y'], 81, 62))
            chomp.play()
            fish_pos_list.remove(position)
            points += 1

    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)

screen.blit(endgame_turtle,(150, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
time.sleep(2.5)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: pygame [has a dependency on libtiff](http://pygame.org/wiki/MinGWBuildingDependenciesByHand#Compiling%20libtiff)

Comment: I have never had to do this before now. Why is it necessary all of the sudden? did I do something in my program or accidentally delete a file? @stuartd

Comment: Have you added new code to your program?

Comment: Not since I posted it. Why are you asking? (Sorry if that is a sorta stupid question) @stuartd

Comment: FWIW: [TIFF tag 37724](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/imagesourcedata.html) (it's an Adobe extension).